# CONEXION SSH - CLIENTE WINDOWS - SERVIDOR LINUX

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

comento la situación, tengo un servidor linux donde he generado las llaves ssh a través del comando ssh-keygen, en la carpeta ssh ha generado los 2 archivos id_rsa y id_rsa.pub.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero conectarme desde un dispostivo windows mediante Visual Studio Code, usando la extensión Remote SSH mi intención es configurar en el archivo config el host, el usuario y la ruta donde está la clave pública que generé en el servidor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es, esto que intento hacer es correcto? El problema que tengo es que no se como pasar esa clave pública generada en el servidor a mi máquina Windows y así poder importarla al puttyGen y generarla con un formato válido para Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno el mismo SSH permite la copia de claves a través del comando:

```
scp usuario@hostremoto:/remote/dir/file.txt /local/dir/
```

También puedes usar rsync

```
rsync ~/Dir1/source.pdf test@192.168.56.100:~/Desktop/test
```

Y en Windows puedes usar pscp el cual lo puedes descargar desde el siguiente [enlace](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html)

```
pscp.exe username@remoteHost:/remote/dir/file.txt d:\
```

Y por ultimo puedes instalar en el server un servidor FTP si es que no está instalado aún, **vsftpd** es un excelente server el cual te recomiendo.